# Tell if HTTP request is Keep-Alive

Tags: php, http, keep-alive

How to tell if a HTTP request is a Keep-Alive connection?

Is it possible to detect via PHP if a HTTP request is Keep-Alive?

If a connection is not Keep-Alive I want to return an error as a part of the API protocol to reduce the use of resources at each SSL handshake and to speed up the communication between server and client

Comment: You should be able to read it from the headers via e.g. this polyfill https://github.com/ralouphie/getallheaders or just a regular header-retrieving function, especially easy if you're on Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it with:

```
function isConnectionKeepAlive() {
    if(getallheaders()["Connection"] == "Keep-Alive") {
          return true;
    } else {
          return false;
    }
}
```